# sort an RSS feed in SharePoint CEWP

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sorting, cewp

need to sort an rss feed alphabetically with javascript.

All I get is the tope 'view positions link'

the debugger gives me this error:
*SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase': object is null or undefined*

this is not working:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAzOfx2c8w9UU2piCi-QfziRRwcONvftZBEURdgjnJbq9oC0AJ3BRlDevnMejQ1U5ax6a0JLTNKz_k1A"></script>
<style text="text/css">
    #positions-wrapper {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
font-size: 11px;
}
#positions {
border: 1px solid #eee;
padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
margin-top: 5p;x
}
#positions-header {
padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#positions a {
color: #4C4C4C;
text-decoration: none;
padding-bottom: 0px;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #888;
}
#positions a:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
#positions .position-odd {
background-color: #e5e1dc;
}
#positions div {
padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("feeds", "1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed('http://other.domain.com/rss_feed_clean.aspx');
    feed.setNumEntries(100);
    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
            var container = document.getElementById("feed");
            //*** adding sort by title ***
            result.feed.entries.sort(function(a, b){
            debugger;
             var titleA=a.Title.toLowerCase();
             titleB=b.Title.toLowerCase();
             if (titleA< titleB)
              return -1 
             if (titleA> titleB)
              return 1
             return 0
            })
                        //*** process sorted array
            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                var title = entry.title;
                var link = entry.link;

                jQuery("#positions").append("<div><a href=\"" + link + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + title + "</a></div>");
            }

            jQuery("#positions div:odd").addClass("position-odd");
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div id="positions-wrapper">
    <div id="positions">
<div id="positions-header"><a href="http://other.domain.com/" target="_blank">View Open Position List</a></div>

</div>
</div>
```